# where are .buildinfo files kept in debian source package?

Tags: debian, security, repository

I have been following the reproducible-builds projects for sometime now and did read/hear somewhere that Debian will start shipping `.buildinfo` files in Debian source files for quite sometime.

I downloaded few source files for some different things few days back, I looked through and wasn't able to find the `.buildinfo` files. Does anybody if Debian has started `.buildinfo` files or not. If not, why ? If they have started to ship `.buildinfo` what is the path where they have put it (a consistent path) and any idea when they will be available archive-wide ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buildinfo files aren’t kept as part of Debian source packages, and they can’t be — they’re not part of the source, they’re a reflection of the build environment used when building a binary package. They are now produced with all package builds, and are uploaded alongside the binary packages. If you have access to `ftp-master.debian.org` you can see them in `/srv/ftp-master.debian.org/buildinfo` (one subdirectory per day, *e.g.* `2017/02/07`); they are also made available unofficially [on this buildinfo mirror](https://buildinfo.debian.net/binaries). They are supposed to be made available officially at some point, but I don’t know when that will happen.

You might find [Holger Levsen’s recent talk with Dennis Gilmore at DevConf.cz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8oEg0p6QLE) on the topic quite interesting; Holger talks about buildinfo files early on in the talk.